# Mongodb CloneCollection vs CopyTo

Tags: mongodb

Im in need to store a copy of a collection in a given time, work on that copy (process which could take 20-30 minutes) and then remove the copy.

The copy itself should be an image of the collection in the given time such that any action that occurs after that time, needs to be ignored.

For that MondbDb have 2 methods which do the same but doing it differently and here comes the question.

`db.CloneCollection` which copies the collection to a new collection (I could find any lock related warnings)

and

```
db.collection.copyTo
```

which copies the document but causes collection-wide lock (which could be a problem for me).

Question is, under what assumptions I can work with cloneCollection and CopyTo.

The question related to not only to the lock making.

I would like to ask for suggestions, hints or any idea of out to get the data as fast as possible without hurting workers using the collection. (It also may be that the answer is not including `cloneCollection` nor `copyTo`).

Its not an open debate, there is pretty much only 1 desicive answer under the following assumptions:

1. The collection may contain up to 50m entries.
2. lock should be reduced to a minimum or none, if possible.
3. There could be a slight time difference from when I start the process till the full clone of the collection is ready. e.g: if I issue a clone in 10:00 and data from 10:09 is included, it'll be ok as long as its not drastically far.
4. Im using MongoDB WieredTiger 3.4

Comment: There are a lot of bold statements in here for someone asking for an answer, and most of which I reserve the right to strongly disagree with. Seems to me that if you really have such large data and such tight constraints then the main factor here is actually "hardware". To which end the logical option given the constraints would be to temporarily take a replica set node "off-line", demote it to a standalone node and run your process reading from that source. This is actually a good way to snapshot a large datasource for a point in time and has none of the problems inherent in other methods

Comment: So if you need a "copy" you are going to discard, then it stands to reason that "read only" is perfectly okay. Such an approach of course needs the resources to allocate to it. But "if the shoe fits..."

Comment: @NeilLunn its a very good idea, I do have 2 nodes. Do you if that's do-able using the C# MongoDB driver?

Comment: Personally I would want to have more than 2 nodes ( and you really should have at least three for a stable replica set,  and at least one more in addition to take off-line for this process ) so there was something stable whilst any node was taken off-line as a member for the replica set. The reason I bring it up is because taking a node out like this cannot possibly lock and would be virtually instant ( relatively speaking ). The "off-line" process basically involves stopping the node and starting it up again, without the replica set options. Scriptable in just about anything.